# Adding a column to dim table post deployment in a cube

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have deployed a cube in Azure Analysis services and also processed my fact and dim tables. Now I want to add a new column to my dim table A. Can someone help me understand the steps I need to do here? Also, if i change this dim table, will I lose all the data present in the cube?

Comment: What is unclear to you about the steps you need to do?

Comment: @mkrieger1 If I update dim table through visual studio and deploy the model again, will i lose all the data i processed in the fact tables?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you do modifications to Cube Dimension, deploying the changes render the Dimension *unprocessed* and unavailable to the Users. You have to do *Full Process* of this Dim. After such processing all fact measure groups which use this dimension become *unprocessed* as well, and you have to process them. This brings in some downtime in providing data from these Measure Groups.
To simplify your job with processing Dimension and Measure Groups - you can specify option `Process Affected Objects` in processing Dim. This will process all Measure Groups affected by the change during Dim processing and reduce the downtime and your efforts.
Some minor changes to the Dim can require only *Process Update* of the Dim, without dropping data and follow-up processing of MGs. But I can hardly tell it upfront.